shinytest2 screenshots showing spinner, even though app is idle
Setup: I have a shiny application with a ggplot. I also have a test script (from shinytest2).
Here's a relevant snippet of the ui code:
shinycssloaders::withSpinner(
  plotOutput(outputId = 'summ_display_hist')
)

Here's a relevant snippet of the server code:
output$summ_display_hist <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(some_data) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = indicator), fill = '#005ea2',
                 breaks = seq(0,100, length.out = 11)
  ) +
  ...
})

Problem: Whenever I run the test, the screenshot that goes with one of my app$expect_values() shows the active spinner, even though the app has been idle (I use a app$wait_for_idle(timeout = 1e+06) right before my app$expect_values()). So I would expect it to show the underlying chart.
Desires Output: A screenshot with the chart, not the spinner.
What I've tried
I checked the corresponding JSON file and that has all the info about the underlying chart, and no mention of the spinner.
When I run the app regularly and do the same steps with the same inputs, everything works similarly as the test, except the spinner goes away once everything has finished loading. I even put a print at the end of the renderPlot to confirm that the chart really was finished loading.
When I run the test manually, i.e. running chunks of code in my RStudio console, the same problem occurs.
I starting trying to create a reprex with a very simple ui and server, and I couldn't replicate the problem.
So I can keep trying, but wondering if anyone has any insight here?
System Info:

Linux 5.14.0-427.37.1.el9_4.x86_64 version #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 13 12:41:50 EDT 2024 RStudio Pro 2024.04.2 Build 764.pro1
"Chocolate Cosmos" Release (65361150, 2024-06-05) for RHEL 9
Using Chrome as the chromium browser for the test. Do NOT have X Server, so can't $view()
Using posit Workbench


It's going to be very hard for anyone to help without an MRE. I've just made one using your snippets and it works fine.

totally understood. As I said, I also tried creating a reprex and had no problems. I was hoping someone might have had this problem before or had any ideas for how to look into it before I start on the reprex journey

working on a reprex
